# Cross tab query with concat field

Tags: mysql, pivot

I want to create a cross tab query for my table. When I use `CONCAT` I am unable to get output successfully. Can anyone help me with my query?

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('CASE WHEN TX_STOP_NAME=''', TX_STOP_NAME, '''  THEN 
    concat('TIME:-',s.TS_ACTUAL_ARIVAL,' HALT FOR:- ',s.NO_HALT_DUR,' STOP NAME:-',s.TX_STOP_NAME) HALT 
    else null  END AS `', concat('TIME:-',s.TS_ACTUAL_ARIVAL,' HALT FOR:- ',s.NO_HALT_DUR,' STOP NAME:-',s.TX_STOP_NAME) HALT , '`')) 
    INTO @sql
    FROM cmn_trip_statistics;
    SET @sql = CONCAT(' select *from(SELECT s.FKYS_TRIP_ID,s.FKYS_REPORT_TYPE,sum(s.NO_HALT_DUR) as totalhalt, ', @sql, '
    FROM cmn_trip_statistics s 
    group by s.FKYS_TRIP_ID,S.TX_STOP_NAME)T where FKYS_REPORT_TYPE=''HALT''');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default length of a [**GROUP_CONCAT is 1024**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Please run this

```
mysql> SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
```

before the query. This will allow for a 1M string as the maximum [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

If you want every session going forwards to have this, add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len = 1M
```

and run this

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
```

MySQL Restart not required

As for the query itself, avoid using newline characters. Change to this:

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('CASE WHEN TX_STOP_NAME=''', TX_STOP_NAME, '''  THEN 
    concat('TIME:-',s.TS_ACTUAL_ARIVAL,' HALT FOR:- ',s.NO_HALT_DUR,' STOP NAME:-',s.TX_STOP_NAME) HALT 
    else null  END AS `', concat('TIME:-',s.TS_ACTUAL_ARIVAL,' HALT FOR:- ',s.NO_HALT_DUR,' STOP NAME:-',s.TX_STOP_NAME) HALT , '`')) 
    INTO @sql
    FROM cmn_trip_statistics;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from (SELECT s.FKYS_TRIP_ID,s.FKYS_REPORT_TYPE,sum(s.NO_HALT_DUR) as totalhalt, ', @sql);
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' FROM cmn_trip_statistics s group by');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' s.FKYS_TRIP_ID,S.TX_STOP_NAME) T');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' where FKYS_REPORT_TYPE=''HALT''');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```